# Cygwin64: Confused about when /etc/bash.bashrc is run?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, cygwin

I have Windows 7 64-bit PC. I have installed Cygwin version 2.6.0 on it in c:\cygwin64 directory.

I am confused that when I open the Cygwin64 Terminal then does configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc` run?

I think this is an interactive login shell, so as per my understanding `/etc/bash.bashrc` is never run. Here is the link of my understanding: https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

But in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file I can see environment variable `PS1` is set. And it is the same value I get when I use `echo $PS1` command. So does that mean `/etc/bash.bashrc` did run?

I may not be understanding correctly "interactive login" and "interactive non-login". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you use `bash` from script when it called as `#!/bin/bash` it is non interactive and bash won't pick up `.bashrc`, but if you run bash as seating in  console then it is interactive and `.bashrc` loaded in this case

Comment: @Alex So whether its interactive login or interactive non-login, the `.bashrc` is read?

Comment: I will answer in "answer" to avoid restriction on maximum characters per comment

Answer (score 1):

#### When I open the Cygwin64 Terminal then does `/etc/bash.bashrc` run?

Short Answer:

Yes. I added some echo statements to the bash startup files and opened a Cywin64 Terminal. Here is the output:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/home/DavidPostill/.bash_profile
.profile
/home/DavidPostill/.bashrc
/home/DavidPostill/.bashrc
$
```

For some reason `~/.bashrc` is called twice, at the moment I'm not sure why.

---

Long Answer:

The shortcut for the Cygwin64 Terminal runs the following command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

The help for `mintty` states:

```
$ mintty --help
Usage: mintty [OPTION]... [ PROGRAM [ARG]... | - ]

Start a new terminal session running the specified program or the user's shell.
If a dash is given instead of a program, invoke the shell as a login shell.
```

So we can see the the trailing `-` on the shortcut command causes a login shell to be run.

What happens next depends on what your login shell is set to.

Assuming it set to `bash` then:

- If it is a login shell Cygwin will execute `~/.bash_profile` if it exists or otherwise `~/.profile`.

  Note that `.bash_profile` will execute `~/.profile`
- If it is an interactive shell Cygwin will execute `~/.bashrc`

> .profile (other names are also valid, see the bash man page) contains bash commands. It is executed when bash is started as login shell, e.g. from the command bash --login. This is a useful place to define and export environment variables and bash functions that will be used by bash and the programs invoked by bash. It is a good place to redefine PATH if needed. We recommend adding a ":." to the end of PATH to also search the current working directory (contrary to DOS, the local directory is not searched by default). Also to avoid delays you should either unset MAILCHECK or define MAILPATH to point to your existing mail inbox.
>
> .bashrc is similar to .profile but is executed each time an interactive bash shell is launched. It serves to define elements that are not inherited through the environment, such as aliases. If you do not use login shells, you may want to put the contents of .profile as discussed above in this file instead.

Source [Customizing bash](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856) answer explains the difference between login and non-login quite nicely. To summarize, under Cygwin, you are already logged in and just opening a new terminal window. It is the same as if you opened a terminal emulator on a linux desktop or were using `screen`.

Comment: So for interactive non-login `.bashrc` is read, but for interactive login `.bashrc` is not read ?

Comment: @ChumboChappati No, in both cases `.bashrc` will be read because it is interactive session. The only case when  `.bashrc` won't be read - it is non interactive invocation

Answer (score 0):

When you opening cygwin's terminal, it is always " interactive login". See `c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat` that contain `bash --login -i`.

According to `bash`'s manual:

> "If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive."

and "--login" is

> "Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell".

What you asking about `/etc/bash.bashrc` - it is system wide initialization file `bashrc` that can be overridden by local `~/.bashrc` or applied in case users directory doesn't have `~/.bashrc`. When you already in cygwin's terminal and will try to run `bash` - it is non-login since you already logged in, but it is interactive session because you called `bash` not from script. If you will call `bash` from script as

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello SuperUser"
```

then it is non interactive and non login invocation. This way `bash` won't read any `bashrc` at all.

Read section "invocation" in [official bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) to better understand how `bash` interpret `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` and order it used.